# Filter user by using alias address - MS Graph

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

How we can filter the users by using an alias mail address instead of the actual user principal name. Like below

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

 var user = await graphClient.Users
.Request()
.Filter("UserPrincipalName eq 'aaa@aaa.com'")
.GetAsync();
```

Now, I'm getting "not found" error when I use the alias address.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general format of `UserPrincipalName` is alias@domain, where domain must be present in the tenant's collection of verified domains.

**To search users when email address is populated as Alternate Email:**

`otherMails` has a list of additional email addresses for the user; for example: ["bob@contoso.com", "Robert@fabrikam.com"].

```
.Filter($"otherMails/any(id:id eq 'user@example.com'")
```

**To search users when email address is populated as Sign-in Name:**

```
.Filter($"identities/any(id:id/issuerAssignedId eq 'user@example.com' and id/issuer eq 'contoso.onmicrosoft.com')")
```

For more information about personal email address, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/65945/view.html).

---

If the alias address you mean is address with SMTP, for example: ["SMTP: bob@contoso.com", "smtp: bob@sales.contoso.com"]. You could use `proxyAddresses`, the "smtp" is required.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=proxyAddresses/any(c:c eq 'smtp:aaa@aaa.com') 

.Filter($"proxyAddresses/any(c:c eq 'smtp:aaa@aaa.com'")
```

Comment: OP wants to filter on email address alias and not on UPN.

Comment: Thanks @pamela, the Second one is worked for me,